# Trying to iterate through all files in local directory without the "." and ".."

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to write a bash script to process a bunch of sub-directories in the directory that its run in. I need to cd into each directory, compile some code, and run the executable. The problem is that when I iterate through the files in my current directory it includes the "." and ".." and I don't want those to be iterated on. What's the easiest way around this?

Current code I'm working with:

```
for file in .* *
do 
echo "entering $file"
cd $file
done
```

Output looks like:

```
entering .
entering ..
```

By the time it looks for other files in my local directory its up too many directories to be useful. How do I remove . and .. from the list that I iterate through?

Apologies if this is a dumb question - very new to bash scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shopt -s dotglob` will make `*` include dotfiles but not `.` and `..`.

[3.5.8 Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know about that one.

Comment: Thank you! That worked - I've seen references to this in my googling but none of them seemed to apply. Thanks again!